# Angular + Selenium: Cannot get value from input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have written my tests in Protractor and I've used an expect statement:

```
loginPage.email.sendKeys( params.login.email );
expect(loginPage.email.getText()).toEqual( params.login.email );
```

However, my test is failing because signUpPage.email.getText() is returning an empty string. I couldn't find what function to call in Selenium's documentation for input field to return the correct value?

In my Protractor.conf file:

```
 params: {
      login: {
        email: 'user@email.com',
        password: 'blahblah123'
      }
```

Error in Terminal:

> Expected '' to equal 'user@email.com'.

So I'm trying to match that the input of the email field is the same as the email address I've sent through. Any suggestions how to do that in Selenium?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is an `input` field, you need to get the value of the **`value` attribute**:

```
expect(loginPage.email.getAttribute("value")).toEqual(params.login.email);
```

Similarly, to apply Saifur's idea here, if you need to wait for the element to contain the desired value, use [`textToBePresentInElementValue` Expected Condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElementValue):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(loginPage.email, params.login.email), 5000);
```

Note that timeout value (in ms) has to be specified.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was missing the timeout component at the end and didn't initially pick that up when I read through Saifur's link!

Comment: Your answer is more accurate. I totally missed the timeout.

Comment: "get the value of the `value` attribute". Nope. What developers 99.99..% of the time want is not the value of the `value` *attribute* but the value of the `value` *property*. When `input` is changed by the user, what changes it the *property* while the *attribute* remains constant (unless there is code added to change it). In their infinite lack of wisdom, the Selenium devs decided that `.getAttribute("value")` would be treated specially and return the value of the *property* rather than the value of the *attribute*. This is sure to mislead people when they use the DOM directly or other tools.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm getting this issue: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined``` Any luck with how you've dealt with this before?

Comment: @Louis that's just a great point! I love reading your detailed comments and answers, always learning something new.

Comment: @RyanDrake could be related to what `loginPage.email` is, please provide the definition.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the value of an input field managed by AngularJS using solely a WebDriver instance there is an easy way to achieve that.

I tested it using the FirefoxWebDriver and it worked perfectly.

Basically you'll have to use the JavascriptExecutor to execute a javascript code in the browser.

If your web project has the jQuery plugin, then you can use the following method:

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();

public String getTextAt(String cssId) {
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        return (String) javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return $('" + cssId + "').val();");
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you want to use raw javascript you can do it like this:

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();

public String getTextAt(String cssId) {
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        return (String) javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return documenet.getElementById('" + cssId + "').value;");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that in this case the cssId should be an id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Probably element load time is the issue here. In that case you can use [ExpectedCondition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) and even match the text you are looking for.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(loginPage.email ,params.login.email));
```

**Update**
Missed the time of Expected condition. Thanks @alecxe

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue(loginPage.email, params.login.email), 5000);
```

Comment: Saifur, I've tried EC.textToBePresentInElement and EC.textToBePresentInElementValue without much luck. I am getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined```. 

Thanks for the link, however, as that's quite useful!